# Difficulty assigning item to a 2d array object in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to assign an item to mapTiles[x][i] each time through a loop like this:  mapTiles[x][i] = mapCols[i]; But it's not working. This is the error I'm getting:

```
incompatible types - found java.lang.String but expected MapTile
```

My code:

```
public class Map {

MapTile[][] mapTiles;
String imageMap;
String rawMap;

// constructor 
public Map() {
    imageMap = "Map_DragonShrine.jpg";
    rawMap = "Dragon_Shrine.map";
    mapTiles = new MapTile[34][22];
}


// methods
public void loadMapFile() {

    rawMap = file2String(rawMap);

    // array used to hold columns in a row after spliting by space
    String[] mapCols = null;
    // split map using 'bitmap' as delimiter
    String[] mapLines = rawMap.split("bitmap");  
    // assign whatever is after 'bitmap'
    rawMap = mapLines[1];
    // split string to remove comment on the bottom of the file
    mapLines = rawMap.split("#");
    // assign final map
    rawMap = mapLines[0].trim();
    mapLines = rawMap.split("\\n+");

    for(int x = 0; x < mapLines.length; x++) {
        rawMap = mapLines[x] ;
        mapCols = rawMap.split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < mapCols.length; i++) {
            mapTiles[x][i] = mapCols[i];   
        }            
    }   
}     
}
```

This is the MapTile class that mapTiles is an object of. I'm not understanding how to pass new MapTile(mapTiles[i]) given what I have. I'm trying to wrap my head around the use of 2d array with class and instances of it.

MapTile class:

```
public class MapTile {
/**Solid rock that is impassable**/
boolean SOLID, 

/** Difficult terrain. Slow to travel over*/
DIFFICULT, 

/** Statue. */
STATUE,

/** Sacred Circle.  Meelee and ranged attacks are +2 and
    damage is considered magic.  */
SACRED_CIRCLE, 

/** Summoning Circle. */
SUMMONING_CIRCLE,

/** Spike Stones. */
SPIKE_STONES,

/** Blood Rock.Melee attacks score critical hits on a natural 19 or 20. */
BLOOD_ROCK,

/** Zone of Death.Must make a morale check if hit by a melee attack. */
ZONE_OF_DEATH,

/** Haunted.-2 to all saves. */
HAUNTED,

/** Risky terrain. */
RISKY,

/** A pit or chasm. */
PIT,

/** Steep slope. */
STEEP_SLOPE,

/** Lava. */
LAVA,

/** Smoke. Blocks LOS. */
SMOKE,

/** Forest. Blocks LOS. */
FOREST,

/** Teleporter. */
TELEPORTER,

/** Waterfall. */
WATERFALL,

/** Start area A. */
START_A,

/** Start Area B. */
START_B,

/** Exit A. */
EXIT_A,

/** Exit B. */
EXIT_B,

/** Victory Area A. */
VICTORY_A,

/** Victory Area B. */
VICTORY_B,

/** Temporary wall terrain created using an Elemental Wall or other means. */
ELEMENTAL_WALL;       

public MapTile() {
}
```

}

Comment: The error message says it clearly. Incompatible types.  Maybe you want String[][] mapTiles

Answer (score 2):

That is because `mapTiles` is a 2-d array of type `MapTile` whereas `mapCols` is a 1-d array of type `String`. You cannot assign a String value to a variable of `MapTile` type. They are `incompatible types` as the error message states.

You might probably want to do something like this

```
mapTiles[x][i] = new MapTile(mapCols[i]);
// where the MapTile constructor takes a String parameter.
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time creating an instance of MapTile. 2d array with class and objects are taking awhile to wrap my head around. I posted the MapTile class code.